# spatie/laravel-permission in controller get the error msg"Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasRoles does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I wanna try to check the role of the auth user.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Newstb as NewstbEloquent;
use Redirect;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;


class NewsController extends Controller
{
    use HasRoles;

    protected $guard_name = 'web';

    public function createNews(Request $request){

        $id=Auth::user()->id;
        $user = User::find($id);
        if($user->hasRoles('TA')){
            return "You are TA";
        }
        else{
            return "you are not TA";
        }

    }

}
```

anything else i didnt set?

when i triggered this function, it will show "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasRoles does not exist."

Have anyone know how to solve it? or any method to debug it?

Comment: Have you added the [trait as stated in the docs](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#usage) ?

Comment: yes i did . i add "Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles" in the User.php

Comment: Why did you add trait `use HasRoles;` in this controller? There is no method named `hasRoles` either it's a `hasRole` or `hasAllRoles`.

Comment: !!!!!!!!! Thanks you very much @IndrasinhBihola ! i didnt notice that the docs said we have add use HasRoles in other ""model"". Therefore, i think i have to add this in the controller

Comment: Your welcome! @Zong

Comment: You don't need it in your controller.